# Update value in DB with comma [,]

Tags: sql

I would like to update the column value as '12345,123456'. Earlier it was '12345123456'. I am using the following query

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET COLUMN_NAME = '12345,123456'
WHERE TC_ID = 'ABCD'
```

But it is showing error as **Error converting data type varchar to float.**

Please help.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: If the column data type is float and you want to store delimited text inside it, you can't. You need to change the data type of this column into varchar.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your internationalization settings say otherwise, commas are not allowed in numeric values.  And apparently, they are not on your machine.

Use a period:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
    SET COLUMN_NAME = 12345.123456
    WHERE TC_ID = 'ABCD';
```

Note that no single quotes are needed for a number.

If you are passing in a string, you can replace the comma with a `.`:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
    SET COLUMN_NAME = REPLACE(:val, ',', '.')
    WHERE TC_ID = 'ABCD';
```

The database should convert the value automatically.

Or, divide by 1,000,000:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
    SET COLUMN_NAME = COLUMN_NAME / 1000000
    WHERE TC_ID = 'ABCD';
```